# How I can display User and Kernel time using ants profiler

Tags: performance, profiler, ants

I'm profiling a code but I want to know if Ants can display `Userprocesstime` and `Kernelprocesstime`(`Privilegedprocesstime`) because I can find just options (Cpu time & wall clock time)